# Ajax page reloading + Foundation

Tags: javascript, ajax, zurb-foundation, reload

I have an issue with my website:

http://td.lbmedia.pl

After clicking on menu's link page smoothly reloads using ajax but... the foundation javascripts are going down. Can anyone suggest me what is the problem?

Comment: can you provide the code samples here? no one is ready to dig the website to find the source code and debug.

Comment: Yes of course, but I've only installed this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

and my javascript which launches the rest of scripts:

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
    $(document).foundation(); });

Comment: My functions.php file:

http://jpst.it/s3iT.

I am not sure what could be usefull for you.

Comment: Please provide the code for ajax! This issue can have multiple reasons, one of the can be that you use .click instead of .on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is event handlers being destroyed after ajax page load, one way to solve the issue is (since I couldn't find the documentation for that plugin) using [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Comment: It still stuck on page refresh and <- back using browser or BACKSPACE, what can be the issue?